# broken fonts on some gnome apps

Tags: gnome, fonts

I’m using Ubuntu 18.04.4 with GNOME 3.28.2, and four gnome apps are suddenly displaying rectangles instead of letters:

1. `gnome-calculator`
2. `gnome-characters`
3. `gnome-logs`
4. `gnome-system-monitor`

For example, `gnome-calculator`:

[image: gnome-calculator with broken font]

and `gnome-system-monitor`:

[image: gnome-system-monitor with broken font]

For what it’s worth, these are all behaving normally: `gnome-character-map`, `gnome-control-center`, `gnome-disk-image-mounter`, `gnome-disks`, `gnome-font-viewer` (ironically), `gnome-help`, `gnome-language-selector`, `gnome-mahjongg`, `gnome-mines`, `gnome-power-statistics`, `gnome-screenshot`, `gnome-session-properties`, `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`, `gnome-software`, `gnome-software-editor`, `gnome-sudoku`, `gnome-terminal`, `gnome-text-editor`, `gnome-todo`, `gnome-tweaks`, and `gnome-www-browser`.

Here’s my output of `uname -a`:

`Linux laptop 4.15.0-96-lowlatency #97-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 1 04:10:58 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I can’t think of anything I did recently that could’ve possibly caused this.

So, how can this be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked on the [#gnome IRC channel](http://irc://irc.gnome.org/gnome), someone recommended this, and it worked:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig/
sudo fc-cache -r
```

I had downloaded a font a week ago, and probably saved it to the wrong directory, which may have corrupted the font cache.  Hope this helps.